# Displacement from a texture in glsl

Tags: opengl, glsl

This is my vertex shader and what I expect from it is to have a correct displacement from a texture. What it does though is taking **every** vertices of my plane upward to a same level

```
uniform sampler2D clouds    
void main()
{
    vec4 position = gl_Vertex;
    vec2 uv = gl_MultiTexCoord0.st;
    position.z = position.z + texture(clouds, uv.st);
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * position; 
}
```

Comment: This could indicate a binding failure or issue with the texture coordinates. Would be helpful to see how that works.

Comment: I am using the same picture (grayscale clouds) in the fragment shader and the color of the plane changes to a plain greyish, could this mean the problem is related to the texture coordinates ? I think there is no problems with binding.

Comment: It sounds like it is. If you render the texture to color and you don't see any variation, then there wouldn't be any variation using the same data in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

I had to declare my position and uv variable with `varying`, and only needed to add one channel from my texture to the 'z' component of my `Position` variable.

```
vertex_shader = """

varying vec4 Position;
varying vec2 TexCoord;
uniform sampler2D clouds;

void main()
{
    Position = gl_Vertex;
    TexCoord = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    Position.z += texture2D(clouds, TexCoord.st).a; 
    gl_Position =  gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * Position;
}
"""
```

I found [this wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Blender) dedicated to glsl programming for blender3D

Comment: No, you don't have to declare varyings for variables you don't use as varyings. Your original code did not work because it conatained syntax errors, and checking the shader's compilation log would have told you so.